# Specify certain values with Facebook Graph request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

I was wondering if there's a method to specify certain values of for instance "story" or "name" field when doing a request to the facebook graph. What I'm looking for is something like the following:

```
/{id}/feed?q={bla}&type={story}
```

Where I want to check a specific person/page's feed on a certain string of text within each story returned.

Hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

Filtering and searching capabilities of the Graph API are very rudimentary.

When any endpoints support additional parameters of that sort, it is usually mentioned in the documentation.

But there is no way to filter a person’s or page’s feed for specific story types and message contents.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'll have to filter with PHP then :)

Comment: And you can't say you would only want results where the "story" field is not empty, right?

Comment: No, that’s not possible either.